# Access modifiers inside a private static nested class in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, static, access-modifiers

I have a "private static" nested class in Java. What is the significance of access modifiers for fields and methods inside this class? I've tried both public and private with no effect on my application.

```
public class MyList<T>{
    private static class Node{ // List node
        private Object item;
        private Node next;
        private Node prev;

        private Node(Node next){
            this.next = next;
        }

        private static Node doStuff(){}
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code as well as your assumption what you areexpecting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two kinds of nested classes: 1. Static (nested class) and 2. Non-static (also called inner class)

Now, the Outer class, `MyList` can access all the members of the inner class `Node`, but you actually use the access specifiers for the members of the class `Node` (nested class) when you want restrictions of some external class accessing it.

Interesting reads: [Source1](http://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/nested_inner_member_and_top), [Source2](http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/859381)

Answer (score 12):

Because it is a nested class, everything in `Node` can be accessed by `MyList<T>`, regardless of access modifier; because it is a private nested class, nothing first declared in `Node` will be visible outside of `MyList<T>`.

So, the one case where the access modifier may matter are methods that override a superclass method(e.g. `toString()`). You can not reduce the visibility of an overridden method. `toString()` must always be declared public in order for the class to compile.

It should also be noted that when private members are accessed by the outer class, the compiler creates a synthetic method (I believe of package scope). This synthetic method is only visible in the .class file of the nested class.

Comment: Good answer. I'd add that the modifiers on the inner class matter only if the inner class is not `private`.

Comment: "when private members are accessed by the outer class, the compiler creates a synthetic method". Does it create the synthetic method when only `private static` members of the static nested class are accessed from the outer class? Supposedly, all static members (including that of static nested classes) are resolved in compile time.

Comment: @andrybak The Java compiler can recognize when an inner private member is accessed by the outer class, regardless of whether it is static or not. It only creates the synthetic accessor method when it is needed.

Comment: @ILMTitan I understand that, my question was about whether or not the synthetic accessor is created when _only static_ members are used in the outer class.

Comment: @ILMTitan I checked my question using bytecode decompiler. And indeed, compiler does generate synthetic accessors private static variables.