# Java Puzzle: modifiers

Tags: java

Can you, please, tell me 
1) why it is possible to assign a constructor as public for a package-visible class? For example:

```
class TestModifiers {
    public TestModifiers() {

    }
}
```

This class can't be instantiated everywhere but in the same package. So that isn't it enough to use a package-visible modifier for a constructor? That is also true with any method(public) in such a class(package-visible)

2) say, in an inner class I have created two **private** variables. Why can I see them from the outer class? Isn't it strange?? For example:

```
class A {
  A(){}

  class B {
    private int b1;
    private int b2;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   new B().b1 = 1;
   new B().b2 = 2;
  }
 }
```

Comment: For your second question - It feels weird and its the way it is :)..its discussed here before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075262/access-modifiers-inside-a-private-static-nested-class-in-java

Comment: Thank you!!! Didn't see this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is **no** value in a non-public class having a public constructor since, as you rightly state, the class isn't accessible outside of that scope. It will compile - that's just the way things are - but many code analysis tools will generate a warning.

There **is** value in a non-public class having public methods *if the class extends or implements a public class or interface*, since the derived class can stand in for the base class or interface type:

```
package mypackage;

class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private final String message;

    MyRunnable(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(this.message);
    }
}

public class Surprises {
    public static Runnable getSurprise() {
        return new MyRunnable("boo!");
    }
}
```

Code outside of `mypackage` can then obtain a `MyRunnable` instance (as a `Runnable`) and call the public method:

```
Runnable r = Surprises.getSurprise();
r.run();
```

I'll ignore your second question since it was answered elsewhere in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Public modifiers are allowed on non-public classes because public methods defined in those classes may need to be overridden in public subclasses.  E.g.

```
abstract class MyBaseClass {
  public abstract void method();
}

public class MySubClass extends MyBaseClass {
  @Override public void method() { ... }
}
```

Rather than impose a restriction on constructors that does not appear on other members, public constructors are allowed on classes regardless of the visibility of the containing classes.

Comment: But you could always give an overridden method greater visibility than the corresponding method in the superclass. In your example above, you could have left the `public` keyword off of `MyBaseClass.method()` and everything would still compile fine.

Comment: That post raises the question again!

Answer (score 1):

1. It may be useful for inheritance.
2. `class B`, `B.b1,b2` belongs to class A, they are inside A.

Comment: Could you, please, be more detailed?

Comment: class B is inside class A. Why B's private members shouldn't be visible for class A?

Comment: 1.) package access would also do for inheritance - if the class has package access, you have to be in the same package to extend it.

Comment: (I was going to suggest a public constructor makes a difference to reflection, but it doesn't)

Answer (score -1):

> 1) why it is possible to assign a
>   constructor as public for a
>   package-visible class?

It's much more convenient then it could be.

Just imagine that you have a public class, and then you understand that you can make it package-private, and after that compiler tells you that there's 45 errors (on every of your public methods).

---

Cannot reply on your second question. I also think that it's weird.

Comment: -1 I read this answer 4 times and it still doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: So did I. Please, give more detailed answer

Comment: If you have 45 different constructors I'd say you have other problems.